# Nsight debugger doesn't hit breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, cuda, nsight

My current configuration :
Visual Studio 2010, 
CUDA 5.5, 
Nsight version 3.1, 
Graphics card driver version 327.23 (latest)

The problem is that breakpoints in __global__ kernels are not hit when starting 
"CUDA Debugging"

Anyone with the same problem? It was possible for me to have kernel breakpoints
on some older version of Nsight & CUDA, but I wouldn't want to downgrade to previous versions.
Thanks.

Comment: "anyone with the same problem?" isn't much of a question. What do you actually want to know?

Comment: If a kernel launch fails you may not hit any breakpoints. Are you doing proper CUDA error checking?

Comment: yes, I am afraid that was it, thanks! Can I give you the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a kernel launch fails for any reason, it's quite possible that any selected breakpoints in that kernel will not be hit.

It's always recommended to do [proper CUDA error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) in your CUDA codes, especially when you are having difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem of breakspoints not beeing hit, after setting my graphics card to TCC mode ("compute-only"), just in case, You did the same.